# Can't run Xcode 8 project; code sign error

Tags: ios, xcode

I recently started my 'developer's path', and the first thing that I have to fight with is a code sign error poping in Xcode. That's the error that appears when I try to run my project:

> >
>   CodeSign Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FunFacts.app
>       cd "/Users/Rafal/Desktop/Projekty XCode/FunFacts"
>       export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>
> > Signing Identity:     "-"

```
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign - --timestamp=none /Users/Rafal/Desktop/Projekty\ XCode/FunFacts/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FunFacts.app
```

> /Users/Rafal/Desktop/Projekty XCode/FunFacts/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FunFacts.app: resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed
>   Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

I tried to do some research, but nothing worked. By that I mean messing around with the terminal. Do you have any idea what's going on?

Comment: Try going to xcode -> Product - > Clean, might help.

Comment: There is an Apple tech note about this message: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1940/_index.html

Comment: try to use automatic mode

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it asap

Comment: @P.Pshen, I still don't get why it worked, but thanks